# overflow error encountered when running gradient descent

Tags: nan, gradient-descent, integer-overflow

I am constantly encountering these kind of **overflow** errors in my python code for **Gradient Descent Algorithm**.

e.g. RuntimeWarning:

overflow encountered in scalar add

RuntimeWarning:

overflow encountered in scalar power

RuntimeWarning:

overflow encountered in scalar multiply

RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in scalar multiply
[Overflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McWVT.png) 
[NaN error occuring because of the overflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VftQA.png)

I tried to typecast the variables to floats ( np.float64('variable')) but sill no result.Can someone provide mme with any solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.